# Jenkins Conditional Deployment

Tags: maven, svn, deployment, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to create nightly builds and deploy them to my maven repository. In order to reduce the daily bandwidth for developers I want to change the deployment logic so that it's only deployed if changes with reference to our latest deployment are detected.

I found some plugins that seem to be suitable, but since I'm not too involved into the Jenkins use-ability I wanted to ask if there is an "easy" way to implement this?

I thought about some simple test before executing the deployment process:
Check if there are changes made within the project code or the dependencies

=> NO: then nothing should be deployed

=> YES: deploy the new version

I just stumpled over the Conditional BuildStep Plugin. But I'm not sure if this plugin fits best for our approach. I don't want to mess up the whole configuration.

FYI: I am using Jenkins 1.608, Tortoise SVN, and the deploy-Plugin 1.1

Every answer and help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Setup your job to run nightly (current configuration)
- Setup a conditional build step (shell or batch, depends on your OS) that will check the revision number in repository and compare to current revision number in workspace.
- If not higher, quit the build.
- If higher, continue build as usual

**Edit:**
To avoid the build even being triggered, here is a theoretical solution.

- Install **[Poll SCM Now](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PollSCM+Plugin)** plugin, this will add a "poll now" button to the job, that polls SCM for changes. If changes found, a build is triggered, if not, nothing happens.
- Configure the polling permissions to anonymous users (else you'd need to implement login/token in next steps)
- Configure the job to poll SCM infrequently (like once a year)
- Configure a cron job (or a scheduled task in Windows) for a nightly schedule
- Have that cron/task do a `curl` or `wget` to `http://JENKINS_URL/JOB_URL/poll`

Comment: Hello Slav,

thank you very much for your answer. That's how I want it to do.
In the meantime I got some things set up.

I'm using `conditional build step` now.

There are some variables I can use. It's no problem to retrieve the retrieve the current revision number.

How can I get the current revision number in workspace?
Or maybe easier: Can I create a variable that just gives me the time passed by since last changes or a timestamp of that time?

Comment: `${SVN_REVISION_1}` is the variable that holds the current (as in after checkout) revision of the workspace for the first module (add `_2` and so on for others). However, in your case, you probably want to perform the check *before* the SCM step. A workspace in Jenkins in just like any other working copy of SVN. You can run command line `svn info` on the workspace folder, and parse for the already checked out revision.

Comment: And you probably need the [pre-scm-buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) plugin for this.

Comment: Hey Slav, thanks for your help.

However I can't use these variables.. I figured out that the conditional build step plugin is kinda doing the right. I just check if the build cause is NOT also triggered by a SCMTrigger (beside the timetrigger). If that's case the job should not run. But that doesn't work.. The condition-logic is working correctly (I used the shell to echo a message if the condition is met), but the build is created anyway..

How can I fix this in the way that the build just doesn't run and isn't marked as failed? Is this possible?

Comment: The build being marked as "failed" can be fixed through [Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin). Configure it to look for something in the logs (your echo message) and when found, set the result as "Unstable". As for "not triggering the build at all"... sorry, it needs to run to check this complex condition. Otherwise, you'd have to take the whole triggering login externally.